# SQL select the top hashtags in the last 24 hour

Tags: sql, mariadb

This is my query

```
SELECT *
FROM posts
WHERE description like concat('%', :hashtag, '%')
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(time,'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') ASC
```

I would like to select from `posts` the top **hashtags** only in the `time` 
**last 24 hours**

PHP TIME FORMAT `STR_TO_DATE(time,'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s')`

EXAMPLE

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY GROUP BY description HAVING like concat('%', :hashtag, '%')
```

Comment: How do you define the *top* hashtags?

Comment: Are you storing dates as strings? It would help if you could share a few records of sample data, and the corresponding expected output.

Comment: the top hashtags are the hashtags in the `post` column `description`  in the last `time` 24 hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get amount of posts with one hashtag you need a `GROUP BY`to be able to `COUNT` them.
On the other hand sorting it by time makes no sense at all.

It would look like this:

`SELECT COUNT(*) as hashtag_count,hashtag FROM posts WHERE time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY GROUP BY hashtag ORDER BY hashtag_count`

Comment: but how it would be if my query is like `WHERE description like concat('%', :hashtag, '%')` ?

Comment: Why would you do that and what's the purpose of this?

Comment: because the hashtag is inside the description like `this is a text description #hashtag `

Comment: Could you please give me an example?

Comment: something like:

`SELECT COUNT(*) as hashtag_count,hashtag FROM posts WHERE time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND description like concat('%', :hashtag, '%') GROUP BY hashtag ORDER BY hashtag_count` 

I don't know if that's right but Is something like this

Comment: Oh...I think I understood your previous example now. So your whole posting is saved in the `hashtag` column? That's not how it is supposed to be and you can't count hashtags like this...

Comment: something like: `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY GROUP BY description like concat('%', :hashtag, '%') ` I don't know is this is the right way but would be something like this

Comment: my hashtags are inside `description` column I would like to extract and grup by , I don't know how to use a regex expression on it `#`

Comment: Why do you do it like this? Were you forced to do so or was it your own idea? Could you change it?

Comment: yeah it was my own Idea how would you do it?

Comment: another try

 `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY GROUP BY description HAVING like concat('%', :hashtag, '%')` 

I think this will make it easier to you understand what I want

Comment: It won't work at all like this as you would have to do this one hashtag at a time. And as you don't have a list of hashtags you won't be able to do this! It would be much better if you would parse the posts after sending and extract the hashtags to a separate table. After doing this you could use my SQL statement.

Comment: you mean `extract the #hastags from text description` and than `create a temporary table with the hastags`?

Comment: Why a temporary table? It could be a regular connection table between the posts and the hashtags.

Comment: because the way the hastags is stored is inside `description column` so I would have to extract the hastags and this way store in a temporary table

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `LIMIT x` do the query.

To ensure that all "hashtags" are set within the specific date, you can add +,- day onto the date as well.

As for the top results, is there something like a score that is given to them?

Comment: Yeah It's a score like top 10 on 24 hours, How my query would be?